# What's the AB Command to Test 1000 Concurrent Visitors

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, benchmark, ab

How can I perform an AB test with 1,000 concurrent visitors in just a second?

Say in 1 second, there are 1000 visitors on my site. And in another second there are 1800. In Another second again (3 seconds) there are already 3,000 visitors?

So the total visitors I have in just 3 seconds reaches up to 5,800.

I'm thinking about this command:

```
ab -k -c 1000 -n 1 http://mysite.com
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong. You can't set `c` > `n`.

```
ab -k -c 1000 -n 10 http://example.com/
ab: Cannot use concurrency level greater than total number of requests
```

Comment: So how can I test 1000 concurrent visitors?

Comment: @jaYPabs: Read the documentaion, search the web, and read http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question?cb=1